# Sum of Fibonacci numbers

Tags: python, algorithm, math, fibonacci

I found this task [here](http://www.spoj.pl/SHORTEN/problems/FIBSUM/).

> Given the ith (1<=i<=35) Fibonacci
>   number F(i) calculate the sum of the
>   ith till i+9th number
>   F(i)+F(i+1)+...+F(i+9) and the last
>   digit of the i+246th one F(i+246)

I have been trying to solve this using python and some tricks(Binnet's formula and a tricky recurrence):

```
 f=lambda n:((1+5**.5)**n-(1-5**.5)**n)/(2**n*5**.5)
 exec"n=input();print int(55*f(n)+88*f(n+1)+f(n+6)%10);"*input()
```

but I didn't yet managed to squeeze thought the give source code limit which is 111 and mine is 115,any hints how to improve my solution?

I am a rather newbie to python so any sort of help resulting in a successful solution will be much appreciated.

Thanks,

Comment: Upvote for Sphere Online Judge. I love that site.

Comment: @yock:Indeed,SPOJ is awesome!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`f = lambda n,t=5**.5:((1+t)**n-(1-t)**n)/(2**n*t)` etc. spends 8 characters `,t=5**.5` to gain 12: three lots of `5**.5` -> `t`. That's a saving of 4 characters, which seems to be what you require.

[EDITED to correct a typo; I had `2*n` instead of `2**n` in the denominator.]

You can save a few more characters with a different twist on Binet's formula: `f=lambda n:round((1+5**.5)**n/5**.5/2**n)`.

Answer (score 5):

Did you try to use this sum formula?

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number#Second_identity ("Second Identity")?

Answer (score 1):

Here is the 110 solution, I had to rewrite the formula though and used @Gareth's suggestion:

```
p=5**.5
f=lambda n:((1+p)**n-(1-p)**n)/(2**n*p)
exec "n=input();print int(f(n+11)-f(n+1)+f(n+6)%10);"*input()
```

Saving another symbol, 109 now (manipulating with `n` and getting rid of `+11`):

```
p=5**.5
f=lambda n:((1+p)**n-(1-p)**n)/(2**n*p)
exec "n=input()+6;print int(f(n+5)-f(n-5)+f(n)%10);"*input()
```

**Edit:** New way to calculate particular number, saves another 4 symbols and allows to avoid `int()`:

```
def f(n):exec"a=b=1;"+"a,b=b,a+b;"*(n-1);return a
exec "n=input()+6;print f(n+5)-f(n-5)+f(n)%10;"*input()
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry I did not read your question properly before posting.  I am glad you at least found some use in it.

---

I don't know Python, but in Mathematica, as generic as possible:

```
f[1] = 1;
f[2] = 1;
f[x_] := f[x] = f[x - 1] + f[x - 2]

t = 0;

n = 35;

For[i = 0, i <= 9, i++, t += f[n + i]]

t += f[n + 246] ~Mod~ 10
```

Or, in terse Mathematica, still without using `Fibonacci` function:

```
f[1|2]=1;a:f@x_:=a=f[x-1]+f[x-2];Sum[f[#+x],{x,0,9}]+f[#+246]~Mod~10&
```

Comment: The question is how to make his already working python code smaller than 111 bytes.

Comment: In Mathematica I would rather use `Fibonacci[]` but +1 as I learned something new in the use of `~Mod~`

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question.  Still, I was trying to provide a generic solution that would easily translate into other languages.

Answer (score 0):

```
p=5**.5
f=lambda n:((1+p)**n-(1-p)**n)/(2**n*p)
exec"n=input();print 55*f(n)+88*f(n+1)+f(n+6)%10;"*input()
```

106 chars as long you don't care about int() function and accept a float

Answer (score -1):

This one prints the Fibonacci series up to n.

```py
def fib(n):    
    a, b = 0, 1
    while a < n:
        print(a, end=' ')
        a, b = b, a+b
        print()
```

Comment: how it's related to sum of fibonacci?